# Only insert into table if item does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

My database has a table called `fruit`:

## Table `fruit`

```
+-------------+
| id | name   |
+ ----------- +
| 1  | apple  |
| 2  | orange |
| 3  | banana |
| 4  | grape  |
+-------------+
```

`id` is the a primary key. I want to add entries to the table, but only if they don't exist already.

## The query

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM fruit WHERE name = 'mango')
INSERT INTO fruit (name) 
VALUES ('mango')
```

## Error

I use a SQL GUI app called **Sequel Pro**, and this query errors with the following:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM fruit WHERE name = 'mango') INSERT INTO frui' at line 1`

## Perhaps

Something fishy may be going on. The query may be stopping at `INSERT INTO frui`. Problem with the app? Or is my query wrong?

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Add a unique index on `name`, then use  `INSERT IGNORE` and check the number of inserted rows.

Comment: @MikeW Can you answer with an example of how to do that please?

Comment: @izolate Looks like someone has beaten me to it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You'd have to use

```
ALTER TABLE fruit ADD UNIQUE (name)
```

and then use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO fruit (name) VALUES ('mango')
```

Comment: Okay, `name` is now a unique key. And the query works as intended. Thanks!