# Update where doesn't exist in php script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to finish a php script that selects all from a table on one server connection and insert all into an identical (dumped clone) table on our second server. My connections are successful and my select query works, but now I just need to figure out my INSERT portion. This is meant to update a table on server 2 from an identical table on server 2, so I only want to insert new records that have occurred since the last insert.

The one way I know I can check if a record exists or not is by checking for `SESSIONID` which is an Auto Incrementing Primary Key. I feel this should be pretty simple for someone who knows there way around an issue like this. Again, I want to connect to server 1, select all from cdrdb.session, fetch results, connect to server 2 and insert those into the identical ambition.session table if they don't already exist.

The route I'm attempting to take by selecting all from the table on server 1 and looping the fetched rows to insert on server 2:

````
 // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);




//Query to select * from Session table on server 1
$query1 = "select * from cdrdb.session";
$results = mysqli_query($conn1, $query1);

foreach ($results as $r => $result) {

//This is where I would create my insert statement for each numRow from the fetch but I 
would need to check ```SESSIONID``` to see if it exists on server 2. If not, insert it.
}
````

If I didn't do the fetch/foreach loop, and I just did the select query, this is the insert statement I would have originally used even though I know `where not exists` is incorrectly used in syntax here:

```
$stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "insert into ambition.session a where not 
exists(a.SESSIONID)");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
```

I don't know that it's possible to do it in that fashion though, without doing the foreach loop. Lastly, if I knew the PHP syntax I could just do my select query and then use INSERT IGNORE INTO ambition.session. However, since cdrdb.session has 35 columns I wouldn't know how to insert all. I don't know if there's a way to do that without putting VALUES(?,?,?,?) with 35 question marks.

I really think the first option with the foreach loop is the way to go, I just need help finishing the loop and constructing my INSERT.

Can someone confirm that is the best way and help me flesh it out?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

I found some posible duplicates for you to take a look:

[How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

[MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

[Only insert into table if item does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928181/only-insert-into-table-if-item-does-not-exist)

and another article outside of stackoverflow:

[How to INSERT If Row Does Not Exist (UPSERT) in MySQL](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/)